# How to decompress MP3 to WAV in Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, mp3, wav

I want to find pitches in raw of wav file using FFT and etc. but before I should to decompress MP3 file.
I am using C# with WinRT, and I'm very limited for third-party libraries which often cause exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try [NLayer](http://nlayer.codeplex.com/).  It's purely managed code (with no P/Invoke), so it should run just fine in a WinRT app.

Disclaimer: I am a major contributor to NLayer.

Comment: Which type of data NLayer ReadSamples gives me in byte array? Can I simply convert bytes to decibels?

Comment: The data is in 32-bit float format.  To calculate decibels, I believe this formula will work: dB = 20 * Math.Log(Math.Abs(sampleVal), 10)

Comment: How about decompressing mp3? Or NLayer doing it without me when I call ReadSamples? Thank you 4 advance.